# How to find Joint Angles or Theta for 7DoF Robotic Arm

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

I am trying to find the joint angles or at least theta to be used to find the Denavit-Hartenberg Parameter for a robotic arm (Baxter's right arm). I have the link lengths and such, but I don't know how to find theta using the link lengths or anything. Help with anything would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that arm is redundant, there are an infinite number of solutions for the inverse kinematics.  Fortunately, Dr. Williams at Ohio U has developed the forward and inverse kinematics for this arm [here](https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical-faculty/williams/html/PDF/BaxterKinematics.pdf).   He describes the complete forward kinematics, and the inverse kinematics two ways:  once for the case where $\theta_3$ is fixed at zero degrees, and again using a numerical approach to resolve the redundant system.